# Return "viewName" + variable in Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have a methd in a `@Controller`, that return the name of the View:

```
@RequestMapping("/viewNameFiest")
public String methodName(){
       return "viewNameSecond";
}
```

How can I add a variable to the "return" line? A variable like this `return "viewNameSecond/1";`

In order to retrieve it with `@RequestMapping("/viewNameSecond/{variable}")`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect:

```
return "redirect:" + <URL in String>
```

In your case:

```
return "redirect:" + "/viewNameSecond/variable"; //create this URL String before return
```